# WebView scale to zoom in

Tags: android, webview, zooming, scale

I use a simple WebView that loads a single site. And I want the content to be just bigger. The site is responsive so there is no problem to scale.

What's interesting is:

- webview.setInitialScale(50);   WORKS
- webview.setInitialScale(150);  DOESN'T WORK

What I need is 150 :)

Any reason why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

You can use this to fixes size based on screen size.
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more usable.